# How do you resize a UIView to fit its contents?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I have a `UIView` which contains two labels. I want the view to resize so that it contains all of the text in each label but the text is spilling out of the view. Here is my code:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell
       
    cell.titleLabel?.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainTextLabel?.text = noteArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18.0)
    cell.cardView?.sizeToFit()
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.cardView?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return cell
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these connstraints

```
CardView // hook it's top,bottom,leading and trailing to parent View

        |
  - titleLabel -  // hook it's top , leading and trailing to Card View  
        | 
  - mainTextLabel - // hook it's top to titleLabel , leading and trailing and bottom to Card View  
        |
```

And remove

```
cell.cardView?.sizeToFit()
```